Is there an efficient way to update / replace a specific value of a dask array in python?
So I have a dask array of integers (1 x 8192) and I want to find an efficient way to replace a specific value.
This is the code I am currently using, which is very slow, because dask is immutable, so in order to replace a specific value it is computed into numpy, the value gets replaced and then it is converted back into dask. This is the code I am using:
self.M[bucket] = (self.M[bucket] & ~mask) | new_val.

self.M is the dask array I am using of length 8192, bucket is the index which is integer, mask and new_val are integers as well.
I used da.map_blocks with the help of chatgpt, but it gave me lots of errors...

Single replacement should not be a problem performance-wise. You have multiple such replacements to do so it becomes slow?

Replacing multiple values at the same time is order(s) of magnitude faster.
I was not able to recreate your solution to compare.
def replace_value(dask_array, index, value):
    dask_array[index] = value
    return dask_array


def multi_replace_value(dask_array, indices, values):
    dask_array[indices] = values
    return dask_array

an_array = da.random.random((8000, 1), chunks=(100, 100))
an_array2 = an_array.copy()
for idx, value in enumerate(np.arange(100)):
    replace_value(an_array, idx, value)
multi_replace_value(an_array2, np.arange(100), np.arange(100).reshape(-1, 1))



I do not recommend using functions, they are just wrappers over indexing. Added only for speed comparison.
